# The expression of the sum of infinite gaussian functions

Tags: calculus, statistics, special-functions

Let $f(x|\mu,\sigma^2)$ be the gaussian function (normal distribution):

$$f(x|\mu,\sigma^2)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }$$

We know its integral over $\mathbb{R}$ is 1.

Now we divide the interval $[0,1]$ into $n$ subintervals, each with an equal length of $1/n$. For each subinterval $[\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}], (i=1,2,\cdots,n)$, there is a function $g_i(x)$:

$$g_i(x)=\frac{1}{n}f(x|\frac{i-0.5}{n},\sigma^2)$$

Namely, a rescaled gaussian function whose mean is the center of the subinterval and integral over $\mathbb{R}$ is $1/n$.

Add them together:

$$G(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n g_i(x)$$

Problem: What's the expression of $G(x)$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$ ?

---

I simulated the result in Matlab by setting $n=10, \sigma=0.08$: ($g_i(x)$ in blue and $G(x)$ in red)

[image: sum of 10 gaussian functions]

By the way, I plan to use $G(x)$ in image processing, so an analytical expression that can be computed directly may be more useful than a mathematical strict yet confusing solution (such as a series). Common special functions like Bessel function are also OK. And necessary approximation will also be acceptable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is fairly well-known to approximate a top-hat function with a series of Gaussian "wavelets."  (I was doing this about 20 years ago.)  To get some analytical perspective, you might try (I admit to not having doing this, so take this with several grains of salt) to expand each of the Gaussian wavelets into a Fourier series (or transform) and compare to the spectrum of a top-hat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $G(x)$ has a simple expression in terms of erf function.
$$
G(x) =\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n g_i(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\exp \left(-\frac{(x-i/n)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right)\\
=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^1 \exp \left(-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right) dy=\frac{1}{2} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)\right)
$$

Below one can find the graph of this function.

[image]

Comment: I happened to get the same answer just an hour ago. Thank you all the same. I should have thought over it before posting. -_-!