# Compute $\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{A^k}{k!}c^{k(k-1)/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the stationary distribution of a certain continuous time Markov chain, and when normalizing I need the probabilities to add up to $1$, which now comes down to evaluating $$\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{A^k}{k!}c^{k(k-1)/2}$$ for $c\in(0,1)$ and some $A>1$. Convergence is easy, e.g. by comparison and ratio test. However, is there any hope in calculating this sum analytically? If this is needed, I am willing to assume special values for $A$ and $c$. Calculating this series seems hard to me, but I don't know that many tricks or special functions myself. Any help or reference is much appreciated.

Comment: With that quadratic exponent, what you have there is what's called a "theta function". It can't be expressed in terms of the usual elementary functions, but a lot is known about such functions. Look for previous occurences of "theta function", here and on MathOverflow, and, of course, on the web generally.

Comment: Integral representation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4517924/closed-form-or-integral-representation-for-sum-n-0-infty-frace-lambda), but no closed form

Comment: Thank you for your help!